# jenkins job not failure even if command inside is failing

Tags: jenkins

I have a shell script which I run from Jenkins. From that script, I am doing remote ssh to a server, changing the user and executing some commands.

Exmaple:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -ex
sshpass -p ${LoginPassword} \
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
      -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
      -tty ${LoginUser}@${SAILPOINT_INSTANCE_PRIVATE_IP} \
      "sudo su - ${SERVICEACCOUNTUSER} -c 'unzip -o  ${TOMCAT_HOME}/${APPLICATION_TYPE}-2.0 -d ${TOMCAT_HOME} || exit'"
```

I want that if any command inside ssh session fails, the Jenkins job would fail. But instead the script keeps on executing. Exit also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

the exit code of last command of the Jenkin's Execute Shell build step is what determines the success/failure of the Build Step. 0 - success, anything else - failure.